# Error while executing Neo4j query include point type

Tags: neo4j, geo

neo4j version 3.4.0

The gps node contains three attributes:

coordinates: point

location: string

type: string

eg:
coordinates: point({srid:4326, x:30.655691, y:104.081602}) ,location: shanghai ,type: gps

I encountered an error while querying:

```
curl http://IP:PORT/db/data/transaction/commit -u xxxx:xxxx -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d "{
"statements": [{
"statement": "match (n:gps) return n",
"parameters": {},
"includeStats": true,
"resultDataContents": ["rest"]
}]
}
"
```

Error is as follows：
"code": "Neo.TransientError.Network.CommunicationError",
"message": "Current context not an ARRAY but OBJECT",
"stackTrace": "org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException: Current context not an ARRAY but OBJECT

But the following procedure was successful

```
curl http://IP:PORT/db/data/transaction/commit -u xxxx:xxxx -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-d "{
"statements": [{
"statement": "match (n:gps) return n.coordinates,n.type,n.loacation",
"parameters": {},
"includeStats": true,
"resultDataContents": ["rest"]
}]
}
"
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to specify the result data content??
Seems like the "rest" type has been added to support old transactional endpoint which is creating the problem here. What specific data are you after?

Comment: eg: coordinates: point({srid:4326, x:30.655691, y:104.081602}) ,location: shanghai ,type: gps @HimanshuJain